# How to extract last number of column in csv file with R

Tags: r, csv

I have a .csv file containing GPS location of a user. One column is called Location Store which contains 15 longitudes and latitudes a user. Examples of Location Store  contents are as follows:

```
121.49961,25.023201;121.499596,25.023188;121.49961,25.02319;121.4996,25.023182;121.4996,25.023184;121.4996,25.023184;121.4996,25.023174;121.4996,25.023167;121.49959,25.02316;121.49959,25.023146;121.499565,25.023125;121.499565,25.023117;121.49958,25.023111;121.499596,25.023132;121.4996,25.023123

121.5011,25.02951;121.5011,25.02951;121.50063,25.029524;121.500534,25.029497;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512

121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512;121.50069,25.029512
```

...

I want to extract the last pair of longitude and latitude from the .csv file with R, How can I do it? Thanks.

So far, I have done the following steps:

```
Trip1 <- read.csv("1.csv", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
Trip1$location_store
head(Trip1$location_store)
LocationTemp <-strsplit(as.character(Location), ";")
LocationTemp
```

## console results

```
...
[[176]]
 [1] "121.52448,25.073643"  "121.52452,25.073673"  "121.524574,25.07372" 
 [4] "121.524635,25.073753" "121.5247,25.073814"   "121.524765,25.07385" 
 [7] "121.52485,25.073881"  "121.524925,25.073938" "121.52499,25.073973" 
[10] "121.52507,25.074041"  "121.52514,25.074095"  "121.525185,25.074121"
[13] "121.525215,25.074146" "121.52523,25.074142"  "121.52524,25.074146"

[[177]]
 [1] "121.52526,25.07417"   "121.525276,25.074173" "121.52529,25.074173" 
 [4] "121.52529,25.07418"   "121.52529,25.074183"  "121.52529,25.074183" 
 [7] "121.52529,25.07418"   "121.5253,25.074179"   "121.5253,25.074183"  
[10] "121.5253,25.074188"   "121.5253,25.074186"   "121.52531,25.074186" 
[13] "121.52531,25.074188"  "121.52531,25.074186"  "121.52531,25.074186"

[[178]]
 [1] "121.52531,25.074186"  "121.52531,25.074186"  "121.525314,25.074188"
 [4] "121.525314,25.07419"  "121.525314,25.074188" "121.525314,25.074188"
 [7] "121.525314,25.074188" "121.525314,25.074188" "121.525314,25.074188"
[10] "121.525314,25.074188" "121.525314,25.074188" "121.525314,25.074188"
[13] "121.525314,25.074188" "121.525314,25.074188" "121.525314,25.074188"
...
```

However, I have no idea to extract the last pair of longitude and latitude value.

Comment: What do you have so far? Do you have it read in yet? Start with `read.csv2` (it's `;` delimited), gather to long form, and then separate lat/lon into different columns, at which point your data will be in a tidy form that's easy to subset. Or just hack out what you need.

Comment: E.g. `library(tidyr); locations <- read.csv2('file.csv'); locations_tidy <- locations %>% gather() %>% separate(value, c('lat', 'lon'), sep = ',', convert = TRUE); locations_tidy %>% tail(1)`

Comment: Hi, alistaire, Thank you for your suggestion, I have added more code that I have done so far, could you please make a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's kind of sloppy this should get what you want from your current code.

```
last_values_per_user <- lapply(1:length(LocationTemp),
   function(i) unlist(strsplit(LocationTemp[[i]][[15]],","))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try your solution.